# Linux Kernel out of tree module JTAG debug

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, texas-instruments, jtag, code-composer

I have an out of tree Linux Kernel module that I am building for a BeagleBoneBlack (am335x) that I want to debug with a Blackhawk USB100v2 JTAG debugger. I am using the Code Composer Studio IDE, so I would like to use there debug view as well. Any ideas on how I could do this? The problem is I don't know if the debugger would understand anything about the dynamically loaded module.

Comment: So you are asking how to load symbols for dynamic module in CCS?

Comment: If so, maybe this TI E2E link will help you: [linux kernel module debugging in CCS](https://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/203974)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want. Too bad in the link they say that they aren't getting a valid stack. Maybe they didn't compile with the right frame pointer settings? Who knows, I'll try it out though. Thanks.